# Rails exception Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `publications`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have mysql database with table `Publications` which have data about publications. And using `mysql` gem to access this data. My Ruby version 1.9.3. OS: Windows 7

I also have a model for geting this data

```
  class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
```

Application starts fine, but when I want to make simpliest query like `Publication.find(id)` i get the exception `Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM`publications

How to solve this?

Comment: what is your rake db:create and rake db:migrate output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. In `database.yml` file need to make following chages:

change `adapter:mysql` to `adapter:mysql2`